# How to attach excel files in an email using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following select statement that extract data from a SQL Server database table:

```
$QUERY = "SELECT * FROM Table1"

$DataVariable = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "MyInstance" -Database "MyDB" -Query $QUERY
```

How can I attach the $DataVariable as an excel file in my email?

I am working on the code below:

```
$Date = get-date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy"
$Day = $Date.DayOfWeek
$DateTested = $Date

$filename = "MYReport_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).XLS"
$OutputFile = "\\server\c$\Output\$filename"
```

I don't seem to go anywhere with this. Can anyone assist please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to build the code below and it worked for me !!!!!!!!!!!!!!:

```
            $DataVariable = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ResultsInstance -Database $ResultsDatabase -Query  $SQL

            $Date = get-date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy"
            $Day = $Date.DayOfWeek
            $DateTested = $Date



            $filename = "MyReport_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"
            $OutputFile = "\\serverName\c$\Output\$filename"

            $DataVariable | Export-csv $OutPutFile -NoTypeInformation          

            $to = "Support"

            $body = "Dear <b><font color=black>$to</b></font> <br>"

            $body += "<p>Please find attached report.</p> <br>"

            $body += "Kind Regards<br>"
            $body += "Dev Team <br>"

            $fromaddress = "xyz@xyz.com"
            #$toaddress = "x@ytm.com"
            $toaddress = "x@ytm.com"
            $bccaddress = "x@ytm.com"
            $CCaddress = "x@ytm.com"
            $Subject = "My weekly report"

            $attachment = $OutputFile
            $smtpserver = "xyzmail" 

            ####################################

            $message = new-object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
            $message.From = $fromaddress
            $message.To.Add($toaddress)
            $message.CC.Add($CCaddress)
            $message.Bcc.Add($bccaddress)
            $message.IsBodyHtml = $True
            $message.Subject = $Subject
            $attach = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachment)
            $message.Attachments.Add($attach)
            $message.body = $body
            $message.Priority = [System.Net.Mail.MailPriority]::High
            $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpserver)
            if ($DataVariable) {
            $smtp.Send($message)
            Write-Host "The variable is not null" }
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your code snippets don't seem to be related to one another
- there is no attempt to mail anything
- I suggest to save $Datavarable to csv (xlsx is also possible)
- this raw example script uses gmail and splatting to fill the parameters

---

```
$QUERY = "SELECT * FROM Table1"
$DataVariable = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "MyInstance" -Database "MyDB" -Query $QUERY 

$filename = "MYReport_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"
$OutputFile = "\\server\c$\Output\$filename"

$DataVariable | Export-Csv $OutPutFile -NoTypeInformation

$emailAcc = "youraccount@gmail.com"

$Cred = Get-Credential -UserName $emailAcc -Message "Enter gmail password for $emailAcc"

$MsgParam = @{                        
    From = $emailAcc
    To   = "recipient@domain.com"

    Subject     = $filename
    Body        = 'blah blah sending $filename'
    Attachments = $OutPutFile
    SmtpServer  = "smtp.gmail.com"
}                        
Send-MailMessage @MsgParam -UseSSL -cred $Cred
```